# AVAsset.LoadValuesAsynchronously 0 tracks in completion handler with m3u8 URL

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avasset

I am trying to prefetch video files with format `m3u8` URL ending.
I run this code:

```
private func prefetch(for url: URL?) {
    guard let url = url else { return nil }
    let asset = assets[url] ?? AVAsset(url: url)
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["isPlayable", "tracks", "hasProtectedContent"], completionHandler: {
        print("asset: \(url.relativeString) tracks: \(asset.tracks.count)")
    })
    assets[url] = asset // save to memory cache
}
```

Basically, it prints 0 tracks always in the asset.track.count print.
I would expect it to print 1-3 as it is the amount of tracks these videos have, and I do not see the performance in video playing is improved using this code.

Is there anything else I am missing to get those tracks prefetched?

Comment: Isn't `m3u` just a playlist format? I think you can only initialize an `AVAsset` with a single piece of media. You would probably have to parse the playlist and create an `AVAsset` for each entry.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel the video is being played this way, isn’t this format also for supporting multiple streaming qualities?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution?